# Scheme - LALR parser generation- input from a string

Tags: parsing, scheme, lalr, guile

We are trying to generate (in guile) a parser and a lexer that read characters from a string instead of stdin.

We started modifying the calculator example included in the code at
http://code.google.com/p/lalr-scm/source/browse/trunk/calc.scm?r=52

The problem seems to be in the following line:

```
(let* ((location (make-source-location "*stdin*" 
(port-line (current-input-port)) 
(port-column (current-input-port)) -1 -1))
```

We tried to define a new input port:

```
(let* ((location (make-source-location "*stdin*" 
(port-line (open-input-string program)) 
(port-column (open-input-string program)) -1 -1))
```

and variable *program* was defined this way:

```
(define program
"int x = 2;
 int y = 0;
 y= x*(2+3);"
 )
```

but it doesn't work, it still waits for standard input characters.

The documentation lacks details, so we can't figure out how we can solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Chris Jester-Young's note about how most of the I/O in Scheme uses the current-input-port as default is spot on.  You'll want to explicitly pass your string port to each of the I/O functions.  See the documentation to `read-char`, for example: http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#Reading.  Note that the `port` argument is in brackets: that's the documentation's notation for "optional argument".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very, very close to the solution! Well, sort of. But here's a start. Look at the original code, around where you were modifying it:

```
(let* ((location (make-source-location "*stdin*" (port-line (current-input-port)) (port-column (current-input-port)) -1 -1))
       (c (read-char)))
  ...)
```

Here, you changed all your `(current-input-port)` to your string port (BTW, don't call `open-input-string` more than once, since you create a new string port each time, each with independent cursors), but it's not the only place that actually uses `(current-input-port)`.

Do you see it? It's actually in the `(read-char)` call! That function actually takes a port argument, defaulting to `(current-input-port)`.

In fact, if you look above and search for instances of `(read-char)` and `(peek-char)`, you'll notice that the use of `(current-input-port)` is pretty much baked into the whole `make-lexer` function. So you will need to change that.

I would suggest that you specify an input port to the `make-lexer` function:

```
(define* (make-lexer errorp #:optional (input (current-input-port)))
  ...
```

then change *all* instances of `(read-char)` and `(peek-char)` to use the input port. Also don't forget to change your `make-source-location` call too:

```
(let* ((location (make-source-location "*stdin*" (port-line input) (port-column input) -1 -1))
       (c (read-char input)))
  ...)
```

Now, you can use `(make-lexer errorp (open-input-string program))` and it should work. (I have not tested it.)

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer, I tried to do as you said, but I get this error: In expression (define* (make-lexer errorp # ...)) Unbound variable: define*.   Have you got any idea of what's the problem?

Comment: What version of Guile are you using? If it's 1.x, you will need to use `(use-modules (ice-9 optargs))` at the top of your program. (Guile 2.x already has `define*` built-in.)

Comment: I'm using the 1.8, while a friend of mine uses the 2.0 and it works...so this evening I'll import (use-modules (ice-9 optargs))..Thank you very much Chris!